# How to use Babelfy or Balnet Java API in a servlet?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, word-sense-disambiguation

I am developing a web application that is able to calculate the semantic distance between pairs of words and 
of course I'm using the Java API version 3.7 BabelNet and Babelfy. The user inserts a sentence (input) in a 
form of a web page and calls a servlet that processes it. 
My problem is that it does not find the "config" folder with all the properties files, I tried to put it in the WEB-INF folder or in other but it does not work.
My IDE is Eclipse and the server is Tomcat.
Does anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks in advance[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zpTx.jpg)

Comment: May be this link can help: http://babelnet.org/guide

Comment: is your config folder ending up in your target/classes directory? if not, a good way to go about this is to have maven copy your config folder which you can have in your root directory to the classes directory via the maven-resources directory. this will have the effect of that folder being copied to the target/classes directory.

Comment: I tried with the maven as you told me, but it did not work, still does not find the config folder :-(